# finding deleted questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

About 2 days ago there was a question about what should be improved about TeX, which was probably deleted meanwhile. Although it was probably largely opinion-based, some of the few answers were interesting. Is there a way to search in deleted questions, or a list of them? Do I need more reputation points for that?

Comment: The most obvious candidate in the last few days is http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35850/73 - closed but not deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least 10k reputation is required to see deleted items, so you won't be able to see deleted material at present. In general, we don't delete many questions, although we do close some. You can search for `deleted:1` (deleted items) or `closed:1` (closed items), with the deleted search only making sense for >10k users!

Comment: `deleted:1` is a moderator-only feature, normal users can't search for deleted posts and also cannot see them in user profiles.

Comment: @Fabian I think it's 10k, actually. As I said in my answer, 10k users can see deleted material, so I'd expect they can also search for deleted items.

Comment: I tried it myself a while ago, it's definitely a mod-only feature. The only way for 10k users to find a deleted question is to either know the URL or the "recently deleted" list in the 10k tools.

Comment: @Fabian That sound like a bug, as there is no reason to expect this to be restricted. One to ask about on meta.so